# python escape markquotes for bash script

Tags: python, bash, escaping, gnupg, double-quotes

I'm writing a small software that must pass to bash one string.
the problem is that bash can't handle characters ", ', `.
I've do a bruteforce software force gpg (if i use only digits and letters, this work without problems), but when my software generate a string that contains one (or more) of these character, i receive some bash errors.
then i need to escape every markquotes inside the string.
so for example, if the software, generate the string a"bc'1, i need to pass this string to bash a\"bc\'1.
but i don't know how to do.

this is the code

```
subprocess.call('gpg -d --output '+decripted+' --passphrase "'+password+'" '+target+' 2>/dev/null', shell=True)
```

Can i use sed? I don't know how to incorporate sed.
I've also thinked to save the generated password to a file, and then read the string from file like this

```
cat fileWithPassword | gpg -d --output OUTPUT_FILE -- passphrase-fd 0 TARGET_FILE
```

i've noticed that in this way (from bash) works, but i think that is not really efficient save and read a file.
is there any way to escape every markquote withoud save it on a file?

Comment: this work, but i've the same problem with \ character, how can i pass \?

Comment: Sorry, what? Backslashes should be escaped just like all other special characters. What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: the problem is that if i write
`.replace("\\","\\\\")`
this replace also the escaped " and ', so instead having `\"` i've `\\"`, so the firts backspace escape the second backspace, and `"` is passed to bash

Comment: Are you using the code from the accepted answer? Scroll past that junk, use `shlex.quote` from the 2nd answer. You shouldn't be doing anything with `str.replace`.

Comment: I've solved. just mut `.replace("\\","\\\\")` before the others `.replace()`.
i didn't know that the order was important

Comment: Alternatively, skip subprocess and shell and use GPGME, [like this](http://files.au.adversary.org/crypto/GPGMEpythonHOWTOen.html#howto-basic-decryption).